# Using Bluemix, how to make a R script constantly do the data analysis from DashDB tables?

Tags: r, while-loop, rscript, dashdb

Using Bluemix, how to make a R script constantly do the data analysis from DashDB tables? Any examples or instructions?

Comment: Are you even going to TRY it on your own?

Comment: If i got it solved, I will not ask at here.

Comment: Your questions does not meet stackoverflow's criteria and it appears to have been downvoted because of this.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on asking good questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write a simple Java program to run R Script over dashDB using rJava package of R. JRI package inside rJava allow you to run R Script. Just create a process which runs a particular R Script with some interval and refresh the results. Using the package is very simple.Install the package and add the JRI jar files in your classpath. Add JRI playroom specific binaries in java native library.

Google it for the example code on how to run R script from Java.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Thanks for the solution by using Java. I am also looking for javascript solution for run it in node.js. Any suggestion?